# How to indicate start of line in less search of man pages?

Tags: regular-expression, man, less

I frequently refer to man bash to recall use of "history expansion" parts(events/words/modifiers). I know that the man part I need is 
"HISTORY EXPANSION". So I type in `HISTORY EXPANSION` in forward search list '/'. Of course less jumps not straightforward to the "HISTORY EXPANSION" part, but instead shows all occurrences of this string in given man. Thus, I thought it would be great to type something like:

```
/^HISTORY EXPANSION
```

so I could jump to "start of line"HISTORY EXPANSION.

Neither `/^HISTORY EXPANSION` nor `/\^HISTORY EXPANSION` work

In less man I see that
...

> `/pattern`
>      Search forward in the file for the N-th line containing the pattern.  N defaults to 1.  The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system.

I see that other men were also looking into this, but with a different purpose:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698364/what-is-the-regular-expression-library-supplied-by-my-system

I followed the steps, but still cannot say for sure what regex version is used on my machine. Here is the shared lib dependencies output for less binary

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/less
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc229cb000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f44968e9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4496524000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4496b12000)
```

So, how to indicate start of line in less search, so I can easily jump to the parts of man I need?

Comment: Typing `/^HISTORY EX` followed by return works for me in the manual of `bash` on a Linux system. I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: man is not really appropriate for a manual this big. I would recommand formats with support for index and/or table of content, like `info` with which you have a searchable index (`i`, then type `history expansion` with tab completion)

Comment: Possibly related: [Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/371062)

Comment: IOW, I can reproduce your issue if I run `man` as `GROFF_SGR=1 MANPAGER='less -r' man bash`. You'd want to make sure `less` is run with `-R` instead of `-r` (for it do _understand_ those SGR escape sequences as opposed to pass them through), or use `GROFF_NO_SGR` to revert to the traditional way of doing bold/underline.

Comment: @Kusalananda set PAGER=more, and your search will fail.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I was kinda assuming that the OP was using `less`... But using the wrong pager would be an issue, obviously.

Comment: He'll either have to correct his setup, or type a couple of extra dots when searching.

Comment: If within `less`, you save the content with `s` and `somefile`, and the run `sed -n 'l;10q' < somefile`, what do you see?

Comment: If within `less`, you enter `!grep -ze SGR -e "^LESS=" "/proc/$$/environ"`, what do you see?

Comment: Well, I guess I indeed missed it. Tried again in man:
/^HISTORY EXPANSION$
and it works. Thanks @Stéphane Chazela

Will try now with info, but so far I get
"No indeces found"

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas here is the output of grep  `LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page bash(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page bash(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$!done  (press RETURN)`

What are we looking here for exactly? Thanks again

Comment: You may need to install a `bash-doc` packages. If the info manual for bash is not installed, `info bash` would just show the dumb man page. Debian systems have been known not to include the bash documentation by default.

Comment: Well, I just checked again and it appears that '^' is treated as start-of-line only for headers(sections) of man. That is, **only** those lines, that are in capital letters.
So I can jump
`/^HISTORY`
but 
`/^history` or  `/^Bash`
does not work.
I see, that non-printable chars need to be checked to understand how exactly the document is formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having tried and experimented it appears that man actually indents lines with spaces. This is the reason I could find  
`/^HISTORY EXPANSION`
and failed with
`/^The history library`(This is the first sentence in HISTORY EXPANSION section). Here is the correct pattern:
`/^[[:space:]]{7}The history library...`

As we can see man/less simply adds 7 "spaces"(ascii dec code 32) in front of each line that is not a section header (in bold, as I see other people speak).
I cannot say for sure whether this is true with all Linux distros/man binaries, but with all I tested so far this is true. To sum up in order to find(from first search) description of '-atime' option in man find use
`/^[[:space:]]{7}-atime`

Answer (score 1):

When man's output passes through more, each bold character is in fact that character, followed by a backspace, followed by repeating that character and then to the next character.  To find something in bold, search for /^H..I..S..T

You'll find it also in the article Stéphane pointed to.

Comment: But `less` understands those and its search facility will work on the rendered text. It's different though when roff uses SGR escape sequences for bold/underline and `less` is called with `-r`.